# How to clear the complete back stack (and possible solution)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities A, B and C.
A is the main activity of my application.
A and C can also be started from the Options Menu, B is started from A.
I would like the following behavior:

1. application starts with A: back stack is {A}
2. from A, I navigate to B   : back stack is {A,B}
3. from the options menu, I start C : back stack is {C}

1 and 2 are trivial but I don't succeed in getting 3 to work.

I tried quite a lot of FLAG_ACTIVITY combinations but without success
and I'm getting the impression that this isn't possible.

I'm thinking about creating a DummyRoot activity that is just used to start another activity (actual activity name to start is passed in Intent.getExtras()).  I can give this DummyRoot activity the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
By doing so, I would get

1. application starts with DummyRoot(A): back stack is {DummyRoot, A}
2. from A, I navigate to B   : back stack is {DummyRoot, A,B}
3. from the options menu, I start DummyRoot(C) : back stack is {DummyRoot, C}

Do you foresee problems with this approach?
Is this needed in the first place or is it possible to clear the back stack in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

So when you press back whilst in C, you want the application to quit? If so, you will need to use Flags in your manifest and when you start the Activity using the Intent. A combination here will allow you to clear the current Task and then start a fresh one with your new Activity in it. It does not seem a valid UX, but should do the trick. Please read up on the FLAGS in the documentation for more info on what they will actually do.

Comment: Can you indicate which flags I should use to remove A/B from the back stack when starting C? I did read through the documentation but didn't found a suitable combination.

Comment: I would have said that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK would be the one to look at, and also the following doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: That looks indeed like a good candidate but ... it's only available from API level 11 and I have to support API level 8 (should have mentioned that to start with).